# Unable to close python socket server using keyinterrupt or programmatically

Tags: python, sockets, server, shutdown

I am creating a socket server in python

```
s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind("127.0.0.1", 9001)
s.listen(5)
```

When a connect a Client using socket.connect() I am able to connect and close the client connection. But I am unable to close the server from ctrl+c or keyboard interrupt using  `s.shutdown(socket.SOL_RDWR)`

Is there a way I can shutdown the python socket server using keyinterrupt or programmatically?

Update:

```
    s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.listen(5)
    
    while True and s:
       conn, addr = s.accept()
       conn.recv(1024).decode()
       conn.send("Test message from server".encode())
       conn.close()
       # Position 4 Signal Here
```

Update 2:

I did try to do this within the loop above in Position 4 "# Position 4 Signal Here". It did not work

```
    import sys
    import signal
    
    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
        sys.exit(1)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

Update:

0$: This is windows 10 OS

Comment: You probably want to look into registering a signal handler.  This should get you started https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-catch-sigint-ctrl-c.  It is probably os specific so you should tag your question with an os.

Comment: You cannot `shutdown` a listener socket. You can only `shutdown`  a connected socket, i.e. what you get after calling `accept`. If the process exits (which happens after Ctrl+C) the server socket is implicitly closed too and no longer listens.

Comment: You should try *closing* the listening socket.

Comment: Yes, I did try closing the listening of the socket it did not work. @user207421

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I did do that. I have updated the code in the question. Can you suggest what to do? I am using Windows 10. In one stackoverflow question it said the issue is OS specific. Is that what it is supposed to be?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes I did try to do that. Can you check Update 2. I used something like that. It did not work

Comment: @Gary: what exactly do you mean with *"it did not work"*? Please state clearly what your expectations were and what you experienced instead. The socket gets automatically closed if the program exits, so what makes you think the socket is not closed?

Comment: 0$: ""It does not go back to the prompt again in win 10."" Shell gets locked and becomes unusable. I am able to close the shell and restart a new window and reuse the port since I am using reuse address. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: 0$: I am sure you must have faced this issue. It is replicable for me here in win 10. Did you try it out. It should give you the same results. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: *"I am sure you must have faced this issue."* - first, I don't even run Win10. And nothing in your post even suggested that you are running Win10. Second, you posted various code snippets but you did not post a complete program - so what should one run to reproduce it?

Comment: 0$: It is a 200 line program. The above code is clean and runs in win 10 as well. @SteffenUllrich I wished someone who used win10 to answer this. This is a real issue and the shell is blocked on ctrl+c. I have however made the change to running server

Comment: @Gary: *"It is a 200 line program"* - then please strip it to the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem. Please remember that it is you who wants help, so it is expected that you invest time to make help possible.

Comment: 0$: @SteffenUllrich Thank you. I just did. Your not reading text or ignorant rant is troubling me and not solving my issue. I appreciate your vigilance but it is hurting more than helping. Can you check this again. Its win 10 and ctrl+c doesn't work and is blocked at shell even with ctrl+c